# MOSFET for active-low digital pin ESP32

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, gpio, esp32

I want to make an input for an ESP32 using a MOSFET for active low. Will this schematic work?

[image]

The source is from a 5 V digital pin. I use a [DMG1012UW](https://atta.szlcsc.com/upload/public/pdf/source/20180307/C156390_15204110338481408006.pdf) MOSFET.

Comment: What happens when the source pin is at 0 V? You need a pull-up resistor on the ESP32 pin to 3.3V, or activate the ESP32's pin's internal pull-up, if any.

Comment: Why don't you just use an inverter that is capable of handling 5 volt inputs?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore You're right, my brain misread R23 as 100k, not 100R. Deleted.